# Code::Blocks git plugin

Tags: git, ide, codeblocks

Does anyone use the Code::Blocks IDE? If yes, can you tell me of a decent plugin for working with git? Seems strange, but I didn't find anything with Google.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no GIT plugin for Code::Blocks available. But you can do it in another way. Select Tools -> Configure Tools -> Add and then fill required fields. Let me show you an example with mercurial (using hgtk):

```
Name:        hgtk vdiff
Executable:  /usr/bin/hgtk
Parameters:  vdiff
Working dir: ${PROJECT_DIR}
```

Now you can select Tools -> hgtk vdiff and ... that's all, you'll see a hgtk vdiff dialog.